# Swift Multiple Alert Dialog Fade Out my Interface to Black

Tags: ios, swift, dialog

Goodmorning all,

In some cases I need to present a lot of alert dialog (overlapped on each other). At the moment i can't find another way to do this because i need to take trace of each user's answer for each question in my dialogs.

So, after 5-6 dialog overlapped i've something like this:

[image: Screen]

my interface is faded out till to black, there is a way to avoide it?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the alert has a slight transparent black background which appears on top of the view. The things is since you add a lot of them, at this point this translucent backgrounds they get combined and you get the non-transparent black one.

One alternative would be to not present the alerts all at once but in sequence. So when the first one is dismissed, you present the next one and so on.

Another alternative would be to write your own custom alerts. Then you could control the background as would be fit your application.

However, it does not seem you are using the alerts for what they are supposed to be used, which is errors or messages the user must know. Maybe there is another solution for you application, maybe using a form or something similar. They are quite an intrusive way to interact with an application, so they should be used accordingly.

Hope this helps and you get to figure out the best solution for your project. Good luck!